# tablesorter does not sort currency as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am currently using the tablesorter jquery plugin created by Christian Bach.
It works great, however I have one little problem. In my table I have a column with that contains a currency as data. This currency is in euro. The problem is that the plugin sorts my values wrong. For example tabelsort sorts de values in this order €33,00 €2,00 €1.000,99 while it should be €1.000,99 €33,00 €2,00

So the comma and dot should be ordered differently. Does someone know how I can fix this?

https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter

Comment: how many columns in your table?

Comment: The table has a total of 8 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the following code:

```
$("table").tablesorter({ textExtraction: function(node){ 
    return $(node).text().replace(/[.$£€]/g,'').replace(/,/g,'.');} 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#theTable").tablesorter({ 
            sortInitialOrder:'desec',
            decimal: ',',
            sortList: [[3,1]] // etc.

    }); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it. It still order it the same as stated in my opening post.

Comment: change it as you in column order above i gave is just an example

Comment: have you used sorter: "currency"?

Comment: I solved it with                                     $("table").tablesorter({
        textExtraction: function(node){ return $(node).text().replace(/[.$£€]/g,'').replace(/,/g,'.');}
    })

Comment: i posted answer for desecending order

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandindg. I wasn't clear enough in my question. It wasn't about the order but how tablesorter orders the value based on where the dot is. I solved it with the code I posted here.